# How to insert an unidimensional array to a function

Tags: c, arrays, function

I can't find the mistake here, I try to insert tha tMax array to the avgMax function.

Error is: Called object 'tMax' it's not a function or function pointer...

My code is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int avgMax(int tMax[6])
{
     int i,avgH=0;
          for(i=0;i<6;i++)
          {
               avgH +=tMax[i];
          }
     return avgH;
}

int main()
{

     int tMax[6],tMin[6],i,j,avgH;

          avgH=0;

          for(i=0;i<6;i++)
          {
               printf("Temperatura maxima din %d zi  : \n", i+1);
                    scanf(" %d",&tMax[i]);
          }

          for(j=0;j<6;j++)
          {
               printf("Temperatura minima din %d zi  : \n", j+1);
                    scanf(" %d",&tMin[j]);
          }

           for(i=0;i<6;i++)
          {
               avgH +=tMax[i];
          }


         printf("Average temperature max = %d",avgMax(tMax(6)));

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: `avgMax(tMax(6))` ==> `avgMax(tMax)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, when you pass an array to a function it is converted to a pointer, so the length that you specify in the formal parameter *tMax* is ignored by the compiler. The recommended approach is to pass the length of the array as a separate parameter. In the modified version below I also use a most convenient *LEN* macro:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LEN(arr) (sizeof (arr) / sizeof (arr)[0])

int avgMax(const int tMax[], int tMaxLen)
{
    int i, avgH = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < tMaxLen; i++) {
        avgH += tMax[i];
    }
    return avgH;
}


int main()
{

    int tMax[6], tMin[6], i, j, avgH;

    avgH = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < LEN(tMax); i++) {
        printf("Temperatura maxima din %d zi  : \n", i + 1);
        scanf(" %d", &tMax[i]);
    }

    for (j = 0; j < LEN(tMin); j++) {
        printf("Temperatura minima din %d zi  : \n", j + 1);
        scanf(" %d", &tMin[j]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < LEN(tMax); i++) {
        avgH += tMax[i];
    }

    printf("Average temperature max = %d\n", avgMax(tMax, LEN(tMax)));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The last but one line:

```
printf("Average temperature max = %d",avgMax(tMax(6)));
```

Should be :

```
printf("Average temperature max = %d",avgMax(tMax));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from here :

```
printf("Average temperature max = %d",avgMax(tMax(6)));
```

with this syntax `tMax(6)` you are trying to call a function named tMax.

To pass your array as an argument change the line by :

```
printf("Average temperature max = %d",avgMax(tMax));
```